# What does @using and @namespace directives do in a Razor _ViewImports.cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

What does `@using` and `@namespace` directives do in a Razor _ViewImports.cshtml file?

`@using TagHelpersBuiltIn
@namespace TagHelpersBuiltIn.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

[_ViewImports.cshtml](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/samples/TagHelpersBuiltIn/Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever namespaces you mention using `@namespace` in the *ViewImports.cshtml* file will be available to your views (.cshtml files) automatically without the use of `@using`. In other words, they will be available *implicitly*. If not mentioned in the *ViewImports.cshtml* file, you will still need to use `@using`.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

> The @namespace directive was designed so the C# classes added to a project and pages-generated code just work without having to add an @using directive for the code behind file.

In other words, if you add the `@namespace` to the *_ViewImports.cshtml* file, then the other files will not need to use `@using` in each one of them.

**What is _ViewImports.cshtml`?**

From the [docs](https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-viewimports-cshtml-file-setting-up-view-namespaces-in-mvc-6/):

> _ViewImports.cshtml serves one major purpose: to provide namespaces which can be used by all other views. In previous MVC projects, this functionality was provided by the web.config file in the Views folder; since the web.config no longer exists, global namespaces are now provided by this file.

**More Explanation**

In MVC5 and earlier versions, if you check the *Views/web.config* file, you will notice xml and amongst it you will notice this or possible more `<add` elements:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Mvc" />
</namespaces>
```

That is basically instructing the Razor engine, that all the *.cshtml* files within this specific *Views* folder will need those namespaces and thus the *.cshtml* files can use those namespaces without `@using` for these namespaces. In MVC6, the *Views/web.config* no longer exists and it is replaced by *ViewImports.cshtml* file which serves the same purpose.

**Ok great, so what is @using for then?**

You will still need `@using` in the *.cshtml* files for whatever namespaces are not imported using `@namespace` in the *ViewImports.cshtml* file. For example, if you have a view named *Edit.cshtml*, then you may have this:

```
@using NamespaceA;
```

Which means this namespace is imported explicitly to be available for *Edit.cshmtl* file. A few other namespaces, which are mentioned in *ViewImport.cshtml* file will be automatically available to *Edit.cshtml* file.

Comment: What's ```@using``` being used for?

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. If you read the documentation here, you can see that it is wrong. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#using-layouts-partials-templates-and-tag-helpers-with-razor-pages

Comment: @anthonystivers Which part of the answer is wrong? I read the documentation and I have quoted parts of the docs in my answer.

Comment: `@namespace` is used to declare what namespace should be used for the folder. I, personally, have not found it to be useful in practice. Largely because it seems to be a redundant feature. I've not found my namespaces to be incorrect even when not using `@namespace` at all in any of my files, nor in `_ViewImports`. To add imports, you use `@using`. Not `@namespace`.

Comment: @anthonystivers No you totally miss the point of `@namespace` and also this answer. `@namespace` is used so we do not have to keep importing certain namespaces in each view. Read the answer again please. If you personally do not find it useful, that does not make the answer is wrong. How is it a reduntant feature and how does it being redundant make the answer wrong?

Comment: It seems the primary purpose of `@namespace` is so that you can reference the Page's Model without having to use the fully qualified name with namespace. It allows you to reference the model as `MyModel`, rather than `MyProject.Pages.MyModel`. I can confirm from my testing that this does, in fact, work this way. If I remove the default `@namespace` directive from my `_ViewImports` file, I start getting errors on pages that reference PageModels without the namespace.

Comment: But if you want to reference something outside of the Page's namespace in many pages, such as `MyProject.Helpers`, the correct solution is to add `@using MyProject.Helpers`. `@namespace` is the wrong solution to use here. I know the documentation doesn't have any details on this. But that is the nature of the documentation for ASP.NET Core. There are a lot of missing things. If you want to see further evidence of this, see the linked gist below, which is the default generated `_ViewImports` file for a Razor Pages project.

https://gist.github.com/tstivers1990/bac0e3fd62311dc51c8a821296cd47f9

Comment: There should only be one `@namespace` directive in the `_ViewImports` file.

Comment: It's easier to think of `@namespace` the same as you would for a class. The difference is, instead of having to declare the namespace in the class file, you can declare it per-directory in the `_ViewImports` file. You wouldn't declare multiple namespaces in a C# class file. Nor should you in the `_ViewImports` file. `@namespace` just says, "All cshtml files in this folder live under this namespace".

Comment: *@namespace just says, "All cshtml files in this folder live under this namespace".* Absolutely NOT. That is totally incorrect.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I assure you, you're wrong. Test it yourself. Create a project with the contents of the linked gist and recognize that the reference to `TestHelper` in `Index.cshtml` produces an error. Now switch the `@namespace` directives so that `@namespace MyProject.Pages` comes first. Recognize that the error goes away. This is because the last `@namespace` directive is the one that wins.

Now return the namespace directives as they are in the gist, and change `@namespace MyProject.Helpers` to `@using MyProject.Helpers` and recognize that the error goes away.

Comment: Here is the linked gist I was referring to. I forgot to link it in my previous comment, apparently.

https://gist.github.com/tstivers1990/e47a4e482dfae437579b8c2b6045ffcb

Comment: Downvoted. This answer is incorrect. See  https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7932. `@namespace` in ViewImports is NOT the same as namespace imports in the web.config.

Comment: Downvoted. This answer is incorrect. This is readily seen by the fact that he uses the plural "namespaces" in his first few words. As Anthony Stivers points out in his answer, only ONE @namespace directive is valid in any .cshtml files. These directives work the same as "namespace" and "using" statements in C# files.

Answer (score 7):

**What is _ViewImports.cshtml`?**

`_ViewImports.cshtml` is used to declare all imports for views residing within the folder containing the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file. It is also used to declare the namespace for all views residing within that folder and, additionally, to declare any tag helpers that should be available to views residing within that folder.

**@namespace**

The `@namespace` directive in a `_ViewImports.cshtml` file is used to declare the root namespace for your Razor Views/Pages. The default generated `_ViewImports.cshtml` file for most projects will have `@namespace MyProjectName.Pages`. There should only be one of these declarations in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file and, in the case that there are multiple, the last one is the one that will 'win', and the rest will have no effect. The `@namespace` directive is similar to declaring the namespace for a C# class file. This just allows the namespace to be declared for all views in the folder, instead of having to declare the namespace in every view.

**@using**

`@using` is used to add imports for all views within the folder. For example: if your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file contains `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, then any views under that folder will have access to members of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` namespace without having to explicitly import them via a `@using` directive.

**@addTagHelper**

`@addTagHelper` is used to declare all tag helpers that should be available to views within the folder containing the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file. The default project template generally includes the following `@addTagHelper` directive in the root `_ViewImports.cshtml` file: `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`.

**Additional Information**

It should be noted that a `_ViewImports.cshtml` file within the `Views` or `Pages` root directory will apply to all sub-directories of the `Views` or `Pages` folder as well. You can also add a `_ViewImports.cshtml` file within your sub-directories to add additional using statements that should only apply to the views within that sub-directory. It's also worth noting that, at least for Razor Pages, even if the root `_ViewImports.cshtml` file declares the namespace as `@namespace MyProject.Pages`, a view within `MyProject\Pages\ASubDirectory` will automatically be given the namespace `MyProject.Pages.ASubDirectory` without adding another `_ViewImports.cshtml` file declaring the namespace within `MyProject\Pages\ASubDirectory`.

**Attribution**

This answer was originally an edit of Coding Yoshi's answer. As such, part of the answer is based on Coding Yoshi's answer.

Comment: If I only have one _ViewImports-file containing all the imports needed for all my views (making them able to access every class in my project) does this make my project heavier/slower (since each view would have all the imports)?

Answer (score 4):

The `_ViewImports.cshtml` file in ASP.NET Core MVC is responsible to provide namespaces which can be used or accessed by other views (i.e. shared namespaces).

- `@using TagHelpersBuiltIn` marks included `TagHelpersBuiltIn` parent namespace (i.e. same as project name).
- `@namespace TagHelpersBuiltIn.Pages` implies declaration of namespace `TagHelpersBuiltIn.Pages` in all views, which enables model classes as declared in `cshtml.cs` file ([example](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/samples/TagHelpersBuiltIn/Pages/Product.cshtml.cs)).
- `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` directive enables `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` library contents will available to all views, which tag helper syntax such like `<label asp-for="Model.PropertyName"></label>` can be used in view pages.

References:

[Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

[The ViewImports File](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/viewimports)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, because it is, in fact, the correct answer. The accepted answer at this time is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> What does @using and @namespace directives do in a Razor _ViewImports.cshtml file?

#### Here is the short version:

- `@namespace` gives each `*.cshtml` file a namespace that *adapts to its directory*
- `@using` gives each `*.cshtml` file access to types that are outside its namespace
- all `.cshtml` files in the _ViewImport's directory and sub-directories are impacted

#### What is a C# namespace?

- A `namespace` creates a scope. Inside the scope, type names must be unique.
- From inside a namespace, files have unqualified access to all the types in the namespace. From outside a namespace, files can only access those types with a namespace-qualified full name (or by using a `using` directive).
- Namespaces exist to prevent naming collisions: two types can have the same name so long as those names are in different namespaces.

Example:

```
namespace Computers {
    // the name Apple must be unique within its namespace
    // from outside its namespace it is Computers.Apple
    public class Apple {} 
}

namespace Garden {
    public class Apple {
        // we access Apple from another namespace via its full name
        public void UseComputer(Computers.Apple appleComputer) { }
    } 
}
```

#### What is a C# using directive?

Using a type's full name can be inconvenient. When naming collisions do not exist, a `using` directive provides a convenient way to access a type from another namespace - without having to qualify the type's name.

```
using Computers;

namespace TechnologyStore {
    // `using Computer` lets us access Apple without qualifying it
    public class SellComputer(Apple appleComputer) { }
}
```

### How does `@namespace` and `@using` work in a *.cshtml file?

A *.cshtml file also has a namespace and a type. We can see that if we drop the following code into a Razor Page or View.

```
// Pages/Index.cshtml
@page
<p>@this.GetType().Namespace</p> // AspNetCore
<p>@this.GetType().Name</p> // Pages_Index

// Pages/Foo/Index.cshtml
@page
<p>@this.GetType().Namespace</p> // AspNetCore
<p>@this.GetType().Name</p> // Pages_Foo_Index
```

The default namespace for a `*.cshtml` file is `AspNetCore`. That's a hassle when the @model is in some custom namespace. If the `@model` is in `MyCustomNamespace`, then we have to do some work to access it:

```
// Pages/Index.cshtml
@page
@namespace MyCustomNamespace
@model IndexModel
<p>@this.GetType().Namespace</p> // MyCustomNamespace
<p>@this.GetType().Name</p> // Pages_Index
```

That isn't too much work; but if we are keeping our namespaces aligned with our directory structures, and if we move the `*.cshtml` file, then we will need to update the `@namespace` statement.

```
// Pages/Foo/Index.cshtml
@page
@namespace MyCustomNamespace.Foo
@model IndexModel
<p>@this.GetType().Namespace</p> // MyCustomNamespace.Foo
<p>@this.GetType().Name</p> // Pages_Foo_Index
```

Now the `*.cshtml` file has the same namespace as its `@model` and thereby gains access to it.

In the above example, to gain access to the `@model`, we could have used a `@using` directive instead of a `@namespace` directive.

### How does `@namespace` work in a _ViewImports.cshtml file?

Having an `@namespace` or `@using` per-file creates a maintenance problem when we reorganize our directory structure. When we put `index.cshtml` into the `Foo` directory, its `@namespace` did not automatically change - we needed to remember to manually change it. That can be a problem if we are using code analysis tools to keep our `*.cs` namespaces aligned with their directories.

This is where the `@namespace` in `_ViewImports` becomes convenient. It keeps the *.cshtml file namespaces aligned with their directories automatically.

```
// Pages/_ViewImports
@namespace MyCustomNamespace

// Pages/Index.cshtml
@page
<p>@this.GetType().Namespace</p> // MyCustomNamespace
<p>@this.GetType().Name</p> // Pages_Index

// Pages/Foo/Index.cshtml
@page
<p>@this.GetType().Namespace</p> // MyCustomNamespace.Foo <- adapts to the directory
<p>@this.GetType().Name</p> // Pages_Foo_Index
```

Not only does each file get a namespace, but each namespace *adapts to its file's directory*.

### See also

We can read about the rationale for the existence of `@namespace` here: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1159